# FHIR R4 contained referecnes, schematron validation fails

Tags: hl7-fhir

I am validating the below Appointment resource (which includes a contained reference) using FHIR R4 schema and schmeatron, and I always get this error:

> dom-3: If the resource is contained in another resource, it SHALL be referred to from elsewhere in the resource or SHALL refer to the containing resource.

From my knowledge the contained reference is well included and referenced, and also the Resource validates against STU 3 schema and schematron, but I am not able to validate against R4 schematron.

What I am doing wrong?

Thanks

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Appointment xmlns="http://hl7.org/fhir">
<contained>
    <Slot>
        <id value="slot159260820191620"/>
        <schedule>
            <identifier>
                <system value="urn:oid:2.16.840.1.113883.3.7482.1.6"/>
                <value value="159"/>
            </identifier>
        </schedule>
        <status value="free"/>
        <start value="2019-08-26T16:20:00+02:00"/>
        <end value="2019-08-26T16:40:00+02:00"/>
    </Slot>
</contained>
<status value="proposed"/>
<slot>
    <reference value="#slot159260820191620"/>
</slot>
<participant>
    <actor>
        <identifier>
            <system value="urn:oid:2.16.840.1.113883.3.7482.3.1"/>
            <value value="143052"/>
        </identifier>
    </actor>
    <status value="accepted"/>
</participant>
```

Answer (score 1):

Nothing.  The schematron is broken.  It should say
`...for $id in f:contained/*/f:id/@value...`

I'll check to confirm whether this is in the list of technical corrections we'll be posting soon.

Comment: Hi Lloyd, thanks for your answer. Do you have any update on this issue. It is just to plan how we overcome it.

Comment: For now, manually edit your schematron as above.  The technical correction was delayed due to a few factors.  We now hope to have it applied by early Oct (2019)

Comment: Hi Lloyd, when I try to apply your suggested change, my Schematron file becomes invalid:  

XPath syntax error at char 65 on line -1 in {...d/@value return $contained[...}: Variable $contained has not been declared)

My Schematron line looks like this: https://pastebin.com/zDb55n5K

Comment: Note that the latest official Schematron at https://www.hl7.org/fhir/fhir-all-xsd.zip has the same problem. Do you mean that we have to change $contained to $id in the official schematron?

Comment: I believe the correct invariant is:
`not(exists(for $contained in f:contained return $contained[not(exists(parent::*/descendant::f:reference/@value=concat('#', $contained/*/f:id/@value)) or exists(descendant::f:reference[@value='#']))]))`

Comment: Thanks, Lloyd! This works. Shall we create a pull request on the HAPI library, or is this something you are already working on? https://github.com/jamesagnew/hapi-fhir/blob/master/hapi-fhir-validation-resources-r4/src/main/resources/org/hl7/fhir/r4/model/schema/documentreference.sch

Comment: You should submit a change request using the "propose a change" link at the bottom of any page in the spec.  (It's a spec issue, not a HAPI-specific issue.)  Certainly we'll get it fixed in R5.  Whether we'll get out a patch for R4 is less clear.

Comment: Ok, thanks! Done: https://jira.hl7.org/browse/FHIR-27916